# Insert silently fail with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a problem with my insert with NHibernate

The transaction begin well,
My select done correctly,
My select next value from sequence too,
And commit transaction,
But no insert appear in my NHprofiler and no Errors appears.
I use Session.OpenSession(ReadCommited) & Transaction
Any idea of what happens ?

**Code**

```
class NHUnitOfWok : INHibernateUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ISession _session;
    private bool _isDisposed;
    private IsolationLevel _isolationLevel;

    public NHUnitOfWok(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
        _session.FlushMode = FlushMode.Never;
        _isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
    }

    internal ISession Session
    {
        get { return _session; }
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        Session.Flush();
    }

    public void CancelChanges()
    {
        Session.Clear();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        Session.Transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        Session.Transaction.Rollback();
    }


    public void WithinNewSession(Action<ISession> actionToExecute, IsolationLevel? isolationLevel = null)
    {
        using (var tempSession = Session.SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (var transaction = tempSession.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel ?? _isolationLevel))
            {
                actionToExecute(tempSession);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public void WithinTransaction(Action action, IsolationLevel? isolationLevel = null)
    {
        Enforce.NotNull(action, "action");

        WithinTransaction<object>(() =>
        {
            action();
            return null;
        });
    }

    public T WithinTransaction<T>(Func<T> func, IsolationLevel? isolationLevel = null)
    {
        Enforce.NotNull(func, "func");

        if (Session.Transaction != null && Session.Transaction.IsActive)
        {
            return func.Invoke();
        }

        using (var localTran = Session.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel ?? _isolationLevel))
        {
            try
            {
                var funcRes = func.Invoke();
                localTran.Commit();

                return funcRes;
            }
            catch (TransactionException ex)
            {
                throw new DataException(Resource.TransactionException, ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Session.Transaction.IsActive)
                    localTran.Rollback();
                throw new DataException(Resource.TransactionException, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsStarted()
    {
        return Session.Transaction != null && Session.Transaction.IsActive;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Session.Transaction == null || !Session.Transaction.IsActive)
        {
            Session.BeginTransaction(_isolationLevel);
        }
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing || _isDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }
        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: The code you use to add your entity is also required, but currently not shown.

Comment: It select my next val from sequence but no insert in my transaction, very strange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FlushMode.Never` may be good for read-only transaction, but for anything else, well, probably not. Its xml documentation states:

> The `ISession` is never flushed unless `Flush()` is explicitly called by the application. This mode is very efficient for read only transactions.

So do not use that by default.
That's my advice at least. I know there is some advices lurking around to use that for "performance" reasons, but check if you have still the issue by commenting that out.
Anyway, I never optimize for run-time performance first, developer performance should be the priority in my opinion. (Unless the application has actual, proven and corresponding run-time performance issues. Or, of course, when the code is an obvious coding horror in terms of run-time execution complexity, such as unmotivated O(n²) algorithms or worst.)

If you want to stick with that mode, call `Flush` on session before committing transactions (or as written [here by Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651678/insert-silently-fail-with-nhibernate/36653485?noredirect=1#comment60900739_36653485), choose `FlushMode.Commit`). But really, this choice is a trap for developers having to work with it.

See the default mode documentation, `Auto`:

> The `ISession` is sometimes flushed before query execution in order to ensure that queries never return stale state. This is the default flush mode.

Are you willing to risk having subtle bugs due to getting unexpectedly stale data in queries occurring in the same session after some data changes?

<sub>Side note: why "complicating" code with `Invoke`? See [this](/a/16309331/1178314).</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was looking all around transaction and session but forget that !!

Comment: `FlushMode.Auto` has it's own downsides. It's not clear when entities are written down to the database and therefore NHibernate's flushing behavior is hard to predict (i.e. developer performance could be hampered by opaque flushing semantics). It might be worth mentioning `FlushMode.Commit` here as well.

Comment: In a transactional context, everything can still get rollbacked, so that does not change much. Unless developers are expecting not to get their changes taken into account in their queries running in same session till they have explicitly caused a flush. But it is then more a lack of knowledge issue about NHibernate. Now if the code use a blend of orm queries and sql queries while doing changes in the same session without explicit flush before queries... Well, that starts to be a bit of an edge case. (And for avoiding "unexpected" flushes, we should also advice to not use db-generated PK.)

Comment: For exemple in Commit mode if you change Entity.name and read it later anywhere else before commit, you haven't change ?

Comment: This depends on many things and discussing that in comment is not well suited. "anywhere"? Loaded from same session, the entity will always have the change, but a query with a `where` on its new name will not return the entity.